# XmlPullParserException expected end_tag

Tags: android, xml

I am getting this error in android with webservice.

When i run android webservice and run android project that time this will occur

So what's problem here?

pls anyone know?

Thanks 
Prashant Adesara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the XML file you are trying to parse is not valid. It is missing an end tag somewhere.